# Hiding a div's class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my XSLT/HTML:

```html
    **<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">
      <img id="img" src="http://i.imgur.com/nK9DEVv.png" />
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="home.html">Playlists</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="../XMLTube.xml#body">Playlist</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="">Playlists</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="portfolio.html">Utilizadores</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="Portfolio.html#NOSLeague">Um utilizador</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="Portfolio.html#PremierLeague">Lista geral de utilizadores</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contacts.html">Vídeos</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="Contacts.html#gui">Vídeo</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="Contacts.html#rodri">Lista geral de vídeos</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h2>Vídeos publicados</h2>
    <article class="lista">
      <h3>Who let the dogs out? - Baha Men</h3>
      <button class="show" onclick="showOrHide()">Show</button>
      <hr class="title" />
      <div class="data" style="display: block;"><iframe width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/He82NBjJqf8"></iframe><br /><strong>De:</strong>Daisy<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Descrição:</strong>My favorite song, lol.<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Related:</strong>None<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de Likes:</strong>1<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de comentários:</strong>1<div class="blank"></div></div>
    </article>
    <article class="lista">
      <h3>Desiigner - Timmy Turner</h3>
      <button class="show" onclick="showOrHide()">Show</button>
      <hr class="title" />
      <div class="data" style="display: block;"><iframe width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ProbPpO_8oo"></iframe><br /><strong>De:</strong>Guicky<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Descrição:</strong>Timmy Timmy Timmy Turner.<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Related:</strong>I'm all the way up - Fat Joe e Putzgrilla - Sentadinha<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de Likes:</strong>2<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de comentários:</strong>0<div class="blank"></div></div>
    </article>
    <article class="lista">
      <h3>I'm all the way up - Fat Joe</h3>
      <button class="show" onclick="showOrHide()">Show</button>
      <hr class="title" />
      <div class="data" style="display: block;"><iframe width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/y2ak_oBeC-I"></iframe><br /><strong>De:</strong>Guicky<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Descrição:</strong>Nothing can stop me, I'm all the way up.<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Related:</strong>Desiigner - Timmy Turner<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de Likes:</strong>4<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de comentários:</strong>0<div class="blank"></div></div>
    </article>
    <article class="lista">
      <h3>Putzgrilla - Sentadinha</h3>
      <button class="show" onclick="showOrHide()">Show</button>
      <hr class="title" />
      <div class="data" style="display: block;"><iframe width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QC4JbIvIhdI"></iframe><br /><strong>De:</strong>Anabela65<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Descrição:</strong>Dá uma sentadinha.<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Related:</strong>Desiigner - Timmy Turner<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de Likes:</strong>2<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de comentários:</strong>0<div class="blank"></div></div>
    </article>
    <article class="lista">
      <h3>Yann Tiersen - La Valse d'Amelie</h3>
      <button class="show" onclick="showOrHide()">Show</button>
      <hr class="title" />
      <div class="data" style="display: block;"><iframe width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uzurqBnALkw"></iframe><br /><strong>De:</strong>Izzie<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Descrição:</strong>A minha música preferida.<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Related:</strong>None<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de Likes:</strong>2<hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de comentários:</strong>0<div class="blank"></div></div>
    </article>
  </body>**

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have a class named data which is going to give 4 div's.

This is my javascript:

```
function showOrHide() {
var j = document.getElementsByClassName("data").length;
var h = document.getElementsByClassName("show").length;

for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < h; l++) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("data")[i].style.display = 'block') {
            document.getElementsByClassName("show")[l].addEventListener("click", function () {
                document.getElementsByClassName("data")[i].style.display = 'none';

            });
        }

        else {
            document.getElementsByClassName("show")[l].addEventListener("click", function () {
                document.getElementsByClassName("data")[i].style.display = 'block';

            });
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, I just want the button that is present in every article to hide the `<div>` beneath it. I basically did two `for`'s that iterate through the classes. What do I have wrong? can you please enlighten me?

Comment: can you please provide any fiddle or proper HTML code not XSLT

Comment: You are iterating through each data node. For every node you find, you start to iterate through each show node , adding an event. If the first data node is visible, you add the hiding event to each button. If the last data is hidden, you arlttach the event for showing to each button - no matter what state the other data nodes where...

Comment: Also, you can greatly reduce the code by storing the result of `document.getElementsByClassName` calls rather than repeated calls on every loop, e.g. `var dataEls = document.getElementsByClassName("data")`, then `if (dataEls[i].style.display = 'block')` and so on.

Comment: As you mentioned you need a button for each article but your script will show/hide everything and not just one. If you want to use pure JS then you have to access source of event in showHide() method and find relative DIV elements.

Comment: seriously suggest not using i for an index counter of one loop and l for another index counter of an inner loop - very hard to read  and easy to get confoosed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample snippet to help you with.

Suggestion would be not to put the handler `showOrHide` in the `HTML`, but to handle it in `JavaScript` as shown in the code below.

Approach would be to:

- Find all `articles` using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- Iterate over each using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and find the `data` element and `button` element
- Attach `click` handler to `button`
- When the button is clicked, check whether the `div` is already visible, if yes hide it; otherwise show it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("article.lista").forEach(function(element, index, array) {

  var button = element.querySelector("button.show");
  var data = element.querySelector("div");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var display = data.style.display;
    if (display == "block") {
      data.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      data.style.display = "block";
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<article class="lista">
  <h3>Who let the dogs out? - Baha Men</h3>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
  <hr class="title" />
  <div class="data" style="display: none;">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/He82NBjJqf8"></iframe>
    <br /><strong>De:</strong>Daisy
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Descrição:</strong>My favorite song, lol.
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Related:</strong>None
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de Likes:</strong>1
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de comentários:</strong>1
    <div class="blank"></div>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="lista">
  <h3>Desiigner - Timmy Turner</h3>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
  <hr class="title" />
  <div class="data" style="display: none;">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ProbPpO_8oo"></iframe>
    <br /><strong>De:</strong>Guicky
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Descrição:</strong>Timmy Timmy Timmy Turner.
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Related:</strong>I'm all the way up - Fat Joe e Putzgrilla - Sentadinha
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de Likes:</strong>2
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de comentários:</strong>0
    <div class="blank"></div>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="lista">
  <h3>I'm all the way up - Fat Joe</h3>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
  <hr class="title" />
  <div class="data" style="display: none;">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/y2ak_oBeC-I"></iframe>
    <br /><strong>De:</strong>Guicky
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Descrição:</strong>Nothing can stop me, I'm all the way up.
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Related:</strong>Desiigner - Timmy Turner
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de Likes:</strong>4
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de comentários:</strong>0
    <div class="blank"></div>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="lista">
  <h3>Putzgrilla - Sentadinha</h3>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
  <hr class="title" />
  <div class="data" style="display: none;">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QC4JbIvIhdI"></iframe>
    <br /><strong>De:</strong>Anabela65
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Descrição:</strong>Dá uma sentadinha.
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Related:</strong>Desiigner - Timmy Turner
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de Likes:</strong>2
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de comentários:</strong>0
    <div class="blank"></div>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="lista">
  <h3>Yann Tiersen - La Valse d'Amelie</h3>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
  <hr class="title" />
  <div class="data" style="display: none;">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uzurqBnALkw"></iframe>
    <br /><strong>De:</strong>Izzie
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Descrição:</strong>A minha música preferida.
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Related:</strong>None
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de Likes:</strong>2
    <hr class="spacers" /><strong>Número de comentários:</strong>0
    <div class="blank"></div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot! Uhh, since I was working with XSLT not pure HTML I had to make some changes. But thanks to you I now have a cool website.

Answer (score 1):

For DOM element manipulation I recomend you to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), it helps a lot. Here is a really good tutorial from [CodeAcademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery) to learn the basics, I used that tutorial when I started.

In jQuery your problem would be solved as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show').click(function () {
        var $div = $(this).siblings('.data');
        if($($div).css('display') == 'none'){
            $($div).show();
        } else {
            $($div).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

As I said, If you are manipulating DOM element jQuery would save you time and lines.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I prefer pure JS. I still haven't learned jQuery...

Comment: Hey there, i inserted your code inside a function so I could call it on the button with onclick="...()". But it's requiring me to double click so it works, can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Did you insert the whole function? Because that function already has the bind to click event on it.

Answer (score 1):

You made two errors in your script, the first by calling the variable "i" in your callback. The second by making a test using = instead of == (if (document(...).display = 'block'). If you are a beginner it could be quite hard to understand the first error. Let's give a try.

You declare "i" in the main scope (window), "i" will have different values, from 0 to "j".

When the for loop is done, "i" will have the maximum value, "j".
And when the callback "click" will be called, the value of "i" will still be "j". But there is are no element for

```
document.getElementsByClassName("data")[j].
```

There are many ways to correct your script.
Via Array.forEach you could use anonymous functions to keep the value of "i" persistent :

```js
var dataElements = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
var showElements = document.getElementsByClassName("show");

dataElements.forEach(function(dataElement, i, dataElements) {
  
  // function(dataElement, i, dataElements) is an anonymous function, created expressly for parsing dataElements
  // in this scope, "i" will always keep the same value
  // but we don't need "i" anymore, because dataElement == document.getElementsByClassName("data")[i]
  
  showElements.forEach(function(showElement, j, showElements) {
    
    showElement.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      
      if (dataElement.style.display == 'block')
        dataElement.style.display = 'none';
      else
        dataElement.style.display = 'block';
      
    });
    
  }),
  
});
```